# jQuery Generating divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a foreach loop to generate divs in jQuery. It's working currently but looks like my divs do not have **SOME** class properties for some reason. This is code i'm using:

```
$("#item-container").append("<div class=\"panel col-md-2 col-xs-4 item\" style=\"height:170px;  border-bottom-color: red;\"></div>")
```

So just simple divs. Now I did some styling like:

```
.item {
margin: 10;
 border-style: solid;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

And that is working just fine. But I have another JS function. Basically it just changes the color of the selected div that has class *item*. Now when I generated divs with PHP my function was working just fine. But now it's not working for some reason. Also, styling above applied but this did not apply for some reason

```
item h5,h6,img{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
   -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
     -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
      -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
          user-select: none;
          -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -khtml-user-drag: none;
 -moz-user-drag: none;
 -o-user-drag: none;
 user-drag: none;
```

if you have any idea what is happening please respond

EDIT: Figured why css is not working, this is function in question:

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    var currentprice
    var itemprice
    itemprice= parseFloat($(this).find('.item-price').html());
    currenptice = $('#currentprice').text();
    if ($(this).hasClass( "selected-item" )) {
      $('#currentprice').text(parseFloat(currenptice)-itemprice);
      $(this).removeClass("selected-item");
    } else {
        $('#currentprice').text(parseFloat(currenptice)+itemprice);
      $(this).addClass("selected-item");
    }
  });
```

Was working just fine when I was generating divs with PHP, not working.

Comment: The last css block you have will apply to every `item` element (`<item>`) that has `<h5>` element inside. I'm not sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `item != .item` note the `.`

Comment: Okay that explain styling but

Comment: why my functions that use .item class are now not working and they were working when divs were generated with php ?

Comment: @Syden I'm not just forgot to copy it, updated question with function code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). On that page, it mentions this fact:

> Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called.

So that might be an issue that is causing your [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) handler not to be called when the user clicks an item (if the click handler is added on elements with class *item* and then we add more elements with that class name). See the example below where a click handler is added to the entire document and based on the *id* or *class* of the item, it takes different actions.

One other change was to delimit the string for the new *div* element with single quotes instead of double quote, which allows double quotes to be used without the need for escape characters.

```
$("#item-container").append('<div class="panel ....');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
  $(document).click(function(clickEvent) {
    var element = $(clickEvent.target);
    if (element.attr('id') == 'add') {
      AddItem();
    }
    if (element.is('.item')) {
      ItemClickHandler(element);
    }
  });
});

function AddItem() {
  $("#item-container").append('<div class="panel col-md-2 col-xs-4 item" style="height:20px;  border-bottom-color: red;"><span class="item-price">2</span></div>');
}

function ItemClickHandler(element) {
  var currentprice;
  var itemprice;
  itemprice = parseFloat(element.find('.item-price').html());
  currentprice = $('#currentprice').text();
  if (element.hasClass("selected-item")) {
    $('#currentprice').text(parseFloat(currentprice) - itemprice);
    element.removeClass("selected-item");
  } else {
    $('#currentprice').text(parseFloat(currentprice) + itemprice);
    element.addClass("selected-item");
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 10;
  border-style: solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
item h5,
h6,
img {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
}
.selected-item {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currentprice">3.50</div>
<button id="add">add item</button>
<div id="item-container"></div>
```

Comment: Now I edited and tested code, I added image to each div (removed that css styling) and when I click on div ItemClickHandler is working fine, but when I click on Img inside that div nothing happens.

Comment: same for any other element inside that div

Comment: It is difficult to know what you have done. Did you add additional handlers functions) to the delegate function? Feel free to modify [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKUh9oZdGKwbCL0GO13U?p=preview) (or use another site like jsbin, codepen, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing a string to the *append()* method. You need to use dollar sign (I.e. $) to create a new div:

```
$("#item-container").append($('&lt;div class="panel col-md-2 col-xs-4 item" style="height: 170px;  border-bottom-color: red;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'));
```